`Error: Invalid AST Node: {}.` when calling API using graphql, graphql-request, and react-query
Getting a repeated Error: Invalid AST Node: {}. error when trying to hit my API using a combination of graphql, graphql-request, and react-query.
Here's the root application where I'm making the call:
import graphqlRequestClient from "./client/graphqlRequestClient";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { graphql } from "./graphql/generated/gql";

import "./App.css";

const getWineTypesDocument = graphql(`
  query GetWineTypes {
    types {
      name
      id
    }
  }
`);

function App() {
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["types"],
    queryFn: async () => graphqlRequestClient.request(getWineTypesDocument),
  });

  console.log({ data, error, isLoading });

  return (
    <>
      <div>Hello World</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

Here's the react-query configuration for graphqlRequestClient:
import { GraphQLClient } from 'graphql-request';

const graphqlRequestClient = new GraphQLClient('http://localhost:4000/' as string);

export default graphqlRequestClient;

I also have what I think are some typescript related errors around the graphql query itself, which may or may not be related:
error 1
error-2
Here's my codegen.ts:
import type { CodegenConfig } from '@graphql-codegen/cli'

const config: CodegenConfig = {
  schema: 'http://localhost:4000/',
  documents: 'src/**/*.graphql',
  generates: {
    './src/graphql/generated/': {
      preset: 'client',
      config: {
        documentMode: 'string'
      }
    },
    './schema.graphql': {
      plugins: ['schema-ast'],
      config: {
        includeDirectives: true
      }
    }
  }
}

export default config

And finally, the relevant versions from my package.json:
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^5.0.2",
    "@graphql-codegen/schema-ast": "^4.1.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-query": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5.5.4",

I've combed through this and from what I can tell, the query is using correct syntax, my codegen.ts is configured corrected, and my graphql request client is also configured correctly. Really struggling to understand the source of this error.

I was able to solve this error by removing the graphql function that was wrapping the query (in getWineTypesDocument), despite that being what the react-query docs suggested:
const getWineTypesDocument = `
  query GetWineTypes {
    types {
      name
      id
    }
  }
`;

This solved the type errors too, unsurprisingly. However, it's now unclear to me if/how I'm actually using what was generated by graphql-codegen or not.

Hi @Carolyn, I'm using react-query + graphql-request and got the same issue, thanks for sharing your workaround, it worked for me as well. But, ideally for a better DX with autocomplete etc, it's better to keep graphql or gql for graphql queries. Not sure why this is happening though.

Related issue: https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/issues/9553
